# How to connect a line of text with a table in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-formatting

Within Word, I would like to know if there is a way to connect title "2.3 Members..." with the table below.

Currently once converted to PDF, the table always switches to the new page while the title stays on the previous page, but this is not ideal from a readers perspective:
[image: PDF view]

In the word document, it looks like this. And yes, there is a formula that makes it maybe more difficult to connect title and table.

[image: word view]

PS: the title is not a title of the table but of the whole section that follows.

Comment: Is the formula above the table a paragraph? Is "keep with next" checked for it? (is the same checked for the table rows?) I suppose it's a mail merge document. How does it look like in Word after populating the values?

Comment: I dont know if it's a paragraph. How can i see that?

Comment: Yes it is "keep with next" for the formula.

Comment: For the table I cannot choose "keep with next".

Comment: The word is the basis for and being fed by an online formular. Once there is value entered in the online form, the PDF is created and only on the PDF I can see the separation.

Comment: You would not choose "keep with next" for the table. It is the "next" being referred to. You would want to turn on display of non-printing formatting marks to see the paragraph marks. The formula has to be in a paragraph, but it may also be in an object that is anchored to a paragraph. Again, a sample would help.

Answer (score 0):

The line above is a separate paragraph in I hope in a heading style. Right-click in that paragraph, choose paragraph from the menu and change the paragraph formatting to include both "Keep with next" and "Keep lines together." These will be on the Lines and Page Breaks tab of the Format Paragraph dialog.

You will likely need to format the paragraph containing your formula the same way.

*It is important that paragraphs before and after the part you want as a block not have "keep with next" formatting. The last paragraph in your block should not have "keep with next" formatting. Otherwise, you can end up with more than a page all having this formatting. In that case Word arbitrarily splits the text.*

Comment: it just did not work. the formula seems to be stopping this change in the formatting. thank you anyways

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gajjxeo6i6owjty/Appl%20table%20caption%20formula.docx?dl=0

Comment: I looked at the sample and it works fine here in Word 365. Here is what I have after adding spaces before the table. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wmtr3rqasx2tqj/deleteme%20appl%20table%20caption%20formula.docx?dl=0  --- It is important that the paragraphs before and after your grouped information not have the formatting of "Keep with next."

Comment: I also noted that everything is formatted using the normal style with direct formatting. This is very poor practice in Word. See the following two articles: http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html  and http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview

Comment: I checked and when I saved the document as pdf the grouping was continued. Here is the pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rzp4nrqr0njef4/deleteme%20appl%20table%20caption%20formula.pdf?dl=0  Note, the links to the documents are temporary links.

Comment: I've tried the solution you proposed and it has for the moment already improved the solution. My agenda is so packed, so I will not be able to try more of what you proposed, but I will certainly get back to this thread to give an update once the time allows

Comment: Will look for an update.